# Ruby fiber "dead fiber called"

Tags: ruby, fiber

Playing round with fibers and I know I'm doing something stupid here. But trying to create a simple enumerable type thing based on fibers (it's obviously trivial using Enumerable). When I run the following I get a dead fiber error after it prints out the first couple of iterations. Does anyone know why?

```
class SumPow
  def initialize(a)
    sum = a
    pow = a
    @fiber = Fiber.new do
      Fiber.yield sum
      pow = pow * a
      sum = sum + pow
    end
  end

  def next
    @fiber.resume
  end

  def each
    loop do
      yield self.next
    end
  end

end

sp = SumPow.new(3)
sp.each do |sum|
  puts sum
end
```

output:

```
3
12
tmp/fiber_enum.rb:96:in `resume': dead fiber called (FiberError)
    from tmp/fiber_enum.rb:96:in `next'
    from tmp/fiber_enum.rb:101:in `block in each'
    from tmp/fiber_enum.rb:100:in `loop'
    from tmp/fiber_enum.rb:100:in `each'
    from tmp/fiber_enum.rb:108:in `<main>'
```

This code on the other hand works completely fine:

```
fib = Fiber.new do
  x, y = 0, 1
  loop do
    Fiber.yield y
    x, y = y, x + y
  end
end
7.times { puts fib.resume }
```

output:

```
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is calling `resume` regardless of state of the fiber.

Check whether fiber can resume by calling [`Fiber#alive?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Fiber.html#method-i-alive-3F)

```
def each
  while @fiber.alive? do
    yield self.next
  end
end
```

**NOTE** You need to do `require 'fiber'` to use `alive?` method.

---

**UPDATE** accoridng to the question edit.

The original code yields only once. To iterate indefinitely, you need loop.

```
def initialize(a)
  sum = a
  pow = a
  @fiber = Fiber.new do
    loop do # <-------------
      Fiber.yield sum
      pow = pow * a
      sum = sum + pow
    end # <-----------------
  end
end
```

Comment: sorry I should have been clearer, what if I wanted to iterate indefinitely using the fiber here?

Comment: @rainkinz, The code in the question yields only once: `Fiber.new do ... end`.